# How to check whether custom list have the particular row or not

Tags: android, arraylist

I made a list of contacts having  2 columns i.e contact name and contact number and now i want to make sure that there should be single entry for name so as to avoid duplication.This is the code i am using for checking whether the to be added row is already present in the custom list or not:

```
if(m_localContactNameHolderArrayList.contains(inputProviderInstance.l_contactName.equals(name)))
   //Do something
else
// Do something else
```

Here `m_localContactNameHolderArrayList` is the array list having 2 columns and

`inputProviderInstance` is the instance of the class for providing inputs to `m_localContactNameHolderArrayList`

Here is the code for inputProviderInstance's class:

```
static class InputProviderClass 
    {
        String l_contactName;
        String l_ContactNumber;
    public String getContactName()
    {
        return l_contactName;
    }
    public void setContactName(String contactName) 
    {
        this.l_contactName = contactName;
    }
    public String getContactNumber() 
    {
        return l_ContactNumber;
    }
    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.l_ContactNumber = contactNumber;
    }
}
```

I searched a lot but have not got any idea.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to iterate over the list and check the name with equals, so:

```
boolean hasContact = false;
for(InputProviderClass ipc: m_localContactHolderArrayList){
    if(name.equals(ipc.getContactName()) hasContact = true;
}

if(hasContact) ...
```